# How to plot geographic coordinates with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, scaling, coordinates, mapping

Hello I'm trying to plot geographic coordinates of a route between real locations. I'm struggling to show the graph in full page or zoomed in. I searched a bit on internet and I can't seem to find the answer I'm looking for.

I'm thinking about either having an alternative to showing the exact positions of the nodes or just finding a method to correctly plot these nodes. Here's what I currently have:

```tex
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,scale=0.8,every node/.style={scale=1}]
  \tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=14pt,inner sep=0pt]
    
  \foreach \name/\x/\y/\z in { -1/45.695555/-73.491674/-1, 7/45.654718/-73.494169/7, 18/45.672313/-73.534913/18, 22/45.661651/-73.549355/22, 32/45.603429/-73.636702/32, 39/45.605645/-73.626765/39, 34/45.610551/-73.619080/34, 33/45.620115/-73.626962/33, 41/45.592402/-73.645209/41, 42/45.602253/-73.637504/42, 44/45.601379/-73.637200/44, 40/45.586000/-73.649305/40, 36/45.594348/-73.625702/36, 38/45.621705/-73.626161/38,-1/45.695555/-73.491674/-1}
      \node[circle,draw] (G-\name) at (\x,\y){$\z$} ;
    
  \foreach \from/\to in {-1/7,7/18,18/22,22/32,32/39,39/34,34/33,33/41,41/42,42/44,44/40,40/36,36/38,38/-1}
    \draw (G-\from) -- (G-\to) node [midway,above,sloped](G-\from-\to){};
    
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Do you know a way to show my content in a full page ?

Thank you.

Comment: the points are so close together that they resemble one point after compilation -- probably you could remove the header 45 and 73 from each coordinate point and convert the remaining digits in a log scale so that there is some gap between them

Comment: If of interest there is the [mercatormap](https://ctan.org/pkg/mercatormap) package.